# Magento - How to get cart items total in header.phtml

Tags: php, magento, xhtml, cart

I am using Magento eCommerce and I have modified my header.phtml via the Blank template. Code, this is my code but it shows blank.

```
 <?php $cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
    <?php if ($cartQty>0): ?>

            <?php if ($cartQty==1): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('<a class="cartgo" href="%s">(1 ITEM)</a>', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('<a class="cartgo" href="%s">(%s ITEMS)</a>', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?>
            <?php endif ?>


    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump $cartQty?

Comment: How i get the Quantity??can please help

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There was an answer to a link before by someone called SUHUR I think, I was going to reward him with the answer but it seems he deleted his own post?

He linked to this: http://nothingtopost.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-get-total-cart-item-in-magento/

I modified my code and this works now on .phtml files.

```
<?php
      $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
      $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
      if($count==0)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(0 ITEMS)</a>',$count);
      }
      if($count==1)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(1 ITEM)</a>',$count);
      }
      if($count>1)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(%s ITMES)</a>',$count);
      }
      echo $this->__('', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));
    ?>
```

Comment: The above didn't work for me, but this did: http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/magento-get-the-total-price-of-items-currently-in-the-cart

Comment: Hi thanks for the post and link, I hope others find it useful. Can you tell me what version?

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
    $cartTotal = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    $cartItemsCount = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
    $cartSuffix = ($cartItemsCount != 1) ? 's' : '';

    echo '<a class="cartgo" href="'.$this->getUrl('checkout/cart').'">
              <strong>'.$this->__('Your basket').'</strong><br />'.
              $this->__('(%s) Item%s', $cartItemsCount, $cartSuffix).
              '<span>[$'.$this->helper('core')->formatPrice($cartTotal, false).']</span>
          </a>';
?>
```

Output:

> **Your basket**
>   3 Items [$32.5]

Comment: Add some text to walk through the code, or maybe a sample of the output.

Comment: How i get the Quantity??can please help

Comment: Hi @JenithSamuel the number of items are stored in $cartItemsCount

Answer (score 5):

`<?php 
$_cartQty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
echo $_cartQty;
?>`

thats all you need for 1.7 if your already running the mage:app which you can't do anything without really.

furthermore, this only shows "item" count, not quantity.

Answer (score 3):

Use the helper object to get the current cart object, and then count the number of items in the cart object.

```
echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

More from http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/how-to-get-number-of-cart-items-in-magento/

Comment: How i get the Quantity??can please help

Answer (score 3):

You can find your cart template here:

```
YOURSITE/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml
```

Within a span with the class of `.count` you'll see this snippet:

```
<span class="count"><?php echo $_cartQty; ?></span>
```

Replace it with this snippet and you'll get the grand total displayed instead:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); ?>
```

Comment: How can i display cart total weight?

Comment: @Rathinam sorry no idea, I haven't used Magento in years, thankfully! :)

Answer (score 1):

When linking to a cart, you should really use `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl()`. The example given would not work if your site is hosted in a sub-domain.

Comment: Who cares? Magento is the biggest pile of crap eCommerce system I have come across to date. We scrapped our plans for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
      $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
      if($count==0)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(0 ITEMS)</a>',$count);
      }
      if($count==1)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(1 ITEM)</a>',$count);
      }
      if($count>1)
      {
        echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(%s ITMES)</a>',$count);
      }
      echo $this->__('', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));
    ?>
```

this works for me thanx...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in phtml file to get the no of items in cart.

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
      $noCartItems= $helper->getSummaryCount();
      echo $noCartItems;?>
```