# Get number of products in Magento cart?

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and a theme I am making from the RWD theme. So,

what I want in my theme is to have the number of products that are in the cart to be shown in the cart icon. Like the image below.

[image: amazon cart]

Comment: What did you already try? There are lots of articles about the topic, i.e. [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925271/magento-how-to-get-cart-items-total-in-header-phtml) could help.

Comment: @SaschaM78 so far not attempted it as you can call me pretty new to magento.

Comment: Especially then I would recommend to try around with to get used to the code and to get a better understanding what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @SaschaM78 Yeah good shout. just wanted pointers so I wasn't running into nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the file minicart.phtml:

/app/design/frontend/vishlibrex/default/template/checkout/cart

it contains the line :

```
<span class="count"><?php echo $_cartQty; ?></span>
```

This ability is included in the rwd theme and the variable $_cartqty is defined as such:

```
<?php
      $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount();
      if(empty($_cartQty)) {
         $_cartQty = 0;
      }
?>
```

So, as the theme itself is a creation from the rwd theme it will include this by default. Add a product to the cart and the number will display. At the first visit/start you have no products in cart thus no count shown.